# Page number when using includepdf

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

Can you recommend an easy way to place the page number on an imported PDF? For instance, when using:

```
\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{last_site/last_site.pdf}
```

`\includepdf` was used twice because the code (of the imported TeX / PDF) would affect (a little bit) the TeX code of the main document. I do not want to rewrite some stuff within the main document nor change the imported TeX code cause it looks fine now. Therefore, the `\includepdf` option was used.

The page number of the main document should be used on the last pages. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

The option `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}` does the trick.

Comment: @Monkey: See: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away