# Can I include the page number when using \includepdf?

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

I'm doing a thesis and I need to include another document I created into the document.

I tried using

`\includepdf[pages=-]{usermanual.pdf}`

And that works well, except that it shows only the usermanual.pdf page numberings, and what I need is to shrink each page and show *both* that page numbering *and* continue the numbers of the main document.

Is there a way to make `\includepdf` shrink the pages?

edit: OK, I have figured out how to scale it (by adding the scale= option) - but the page numbering is still gone. How do I get it back?

Comment: I guess your problem is not new, but there are other options than shrinking which might be better
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101523/page-number-when-using-includepdf?rq=1
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21248/how-to-add-a-pagenumber-of-included-pdf-sides

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is quite easy, you don't even have to shrink the page, just add the option `pagecommand={}` to `\includepdf`
e.g.:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{GameTheoryTutorial10.pdf}
```